# Why's my Laravel site showing a 404 error after configuring the default file?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, debugging

I'm not sure why my Laravel site is displaying a 404 error.  I'm fairly certain I've configured everything the way it should be, including the `root /home/web/my_project/public;` part (which's the entry point of the site) but for the life of me, I can't figure out why I still get a 404.

I'm open to any suggestions and/or changes.  Thanks in advance.

Below is the content of the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file:

```php
server {  
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/web/my_project/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my full NGINX config file (I use it on my docker compose dev container for local Laravels):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.php;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

What I think the error is for you is that, you do not have all of this in your `location ~ \.php$ {`:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

Try having it like that and see what happens